# Sort CSV on new value and print top 10 lines

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column by dividing two pre existing columns, sorting the csv descending on the new column, then printing out the new top 10 lines. Here is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

#loading the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')

#Create column for calculated profitability
df['Profitability'] = df['revenue_adj'] / df['budget_adj']


df = sorted(df['Profitability'], key=float)
df.head(10)
```

I can calculate the "Profitability" column but I can't seem to sort by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Profitability', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Nope, still outputs the file in the same order.

Comment: df.sort_values(by='Profitability', ascending=False)

Comment: reassigned the variable.

Comment: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c87e6a2e-4011-4374-b838-be6fdc906e23/?i=true

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would just have to add asdending = False to the answer above...

```
df.sort_values(by = ‘Profitability’, ascending  = False)
```

On mobile now. Not sure off hand if you can add the .head(10) to the end of the code above or if you’d have to create a new dataframe...

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ‘Profitability’, ascending  = False)
df.head(10)
```